# How to filter day by select and foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

**I want to know how can i do to only keep the day of the first select and remove the other from the other select but without DELETE it like just keep it in a variable.**

*I've already tried to do a foreach but i don't understand how to do it.*

```
function generateRestaurant($pdo){
    echo "generateRestaurant()";

    $startTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j')+1, date('Y')) - ((date('N'))*3600*24);

    $dateDebut = date('Y-m-d', $startTime);

    $dateFin = date('Y-m-d');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM events as e 
    LEFT JOIN restaurants as r ON e.restaurant_id =  r.id_restaurant
    WHERE jour >= '.$dateDebut.' AND jour <= '.$dateFin.' ';
    $prep = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute(); 

    echo $query;
    print_r($datas);

        selectRestaurants($pdo);
}
```

**The selectRestaurants function :**

```
function selectRestaurants($pdo){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM restaurants as r 
    LEFT JOIN types as t ON r.type_id = t.id_type
    LEFT JOIN agences as a ON r.agence_id =  a.id_agence'; // Tous les éléments de ta table => TABLEAU
    $prep = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute(); 

    $datas = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $datas;
}
```

**Database :**

```
agences : not used in this example.
events : id_event --- restaurant_id --- jour.
restaurants : id_restaurant --- nom --- type_id --- lieu --- agence_id --- horaire --- tickets.
types : not used in this example.
users : not used in this example.
```

What i need is to only get the restaurants of the week by filter them with my first select and remove the other to only keep the days i want.

This is an algorythm to generate where we are going to eat by using FullCalendar and what we already ate in the weeks to not eat in the same restaurants and type of restaurant two days long.

*EDIT*

I've it's okay, i have resolved my problem.

**Here the solution :**

function generateRestaurant($pdo){

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); 
$startTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j')+1, date('Y')) - ((date('N'))*3600*24);

$dateDebut = date('Y-m-d', $startTime);
$dateFin = date('Y-m-d');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM events as e 
LEFT JOIN restaurants as r ON e.restaurant_id =  r.id_restaurant
WHERE e.jour >= "'.$dateDebut.'" AND e.jour <= "'.$dateFin.'" ';
$prep = $pdo->prepare($query);
$prep->execute(); 


$restaurantsSemaine = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$restaurants = selectRestaurants($pdo);

$currentDay = strftime("%A");


foreach($restaurants as $key => $data){
    $currentIdRestaurant = $data['id_restaurant'];

    foreach($restaurantsSemaine as $restaurant){
        if($currentIdRestaurant == $restaurant['id_restaurant']){
            unset($restaurants[$key]);
        }
    }

    if($data[$currentDay] == 0 && isset($restaurants[$key])){
        unset($restaurants[$key]);
    }

}

shuffle($restaurants);

return reset($restaurants);
```

}

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Nope that's pdo bro

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what you are trying to do. In your PHP code, you have **foreach($datas as $data){**, but $datas has not been assigned a value. And then within that foreach loop you are repeatedly executing **$prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)** although $prep does not change value and you are assigning the result to **data**, which is the variable that is the loop variable for this foreach loop. None of this makes any sense. It would help if you could describe each table in detail with sample data and what the results of your query should be.

Comment: is this Parameterized queries? `jour >= '.$dateDebut.' AND jour <= '.$dateFin.' ';`

Comment: No this is my creation, i edit the post to get more clear

Comment: I goona edit to show you db schema

Comment: data and expected output too. Still not clear what you need.

Comment: without data is hard to guess what you need.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you don't need data, what uineed is just to get all dat who are between $datedebut and $ datefin and rend() them

Comment: You can simply `JOIN events` to the last query, and then filter on `jour` in that query.

Comment: @Barmar nope, that's not that easy

Comment: Yes is that easy. But again if you dont provide some data I cant write the query for you. So good luck

Comment: You can also do the date arithmetic in MySQL: `WHERE jour BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURDATE()`

Comment: Save yourself (and us) some misery. Never use `SELECT *`